# How to output periodogram result to a list in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, fft

I have a time domain data. After I did discrete fourier transform with Periodogram, how can I output the plot into a list for further manipulation?

```
Periodogram[data[[All, 2]], SampleRate -> 3000000/0.01, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], PlotRange -> {{100000000 - 10000, 100000000 + 10000}, All}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is usually an associated function in instances like this.  In this case `PeriodogramArray` outputs the data.

```
data = Table[
   2 Sin[0.2 Pi n ] + Sin[0.5 Pi n] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}],
   {n, 0, 127}];

Periodogram[data]
```

[image]

```
magdata = PeriodogramArray[data];

ListLinePlot[10 Log[10, magdata], PlotRange -> {{0, Length[magdata]/2}, All}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `List` can be extracted from the `Periodogram` output, based on its `InputForm`, as follow.  (We begin with some made-up data.)

```
data = Table[2 Sin[0.2 \[Pi] n ] + Sin[0.5 \[Pi] n] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n, 0, 127}];
plot = Periodogram[data, SampleRate -> 3000000/0.01, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]];
```

Next, we use `Position` to locate the desired quantities within the plot and extract them.

```
plot[[First@Position[plot, Line] /. {0 -> 1} /. List -> Sequence]]
(* {{0., -8.99487}, {2.38095*10^6, 1.60543}, {4.7619*10^6, 1.82102}, ... *)
```